# Create SQL update/backup script from selected entities

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Is it possible to create a backup/update script from a list of selected entities of a table?

```
var entities = context.Entities.Where(e => e.Id == id);
var string GetBackupScript(entities);

string GetBackupScript(IQueryable entities)
{
    // return script that could be used for restoring the selected rows
}
```

Comment: what kind of objects are in entities? if it's just for backing up databases or tables then take a look at this: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/rohatash/creating-sql-server-backup-file-with-c-sharp/

Comment: The mentioned entities are a small selection (full rows) from one table. The link you provided only shows how to make a backup of a full table, but is there a way constrain the backup to specific rows?

Comment: what db system are you using? sql server, mysql, oracle?

Comment: if you are using mysql you can use mysqldump to back up single rows: http://www.thingy-ma-jig.co.uk/blog/11-07-2011/export-a-single-row-from-a-database-as-mysql

Comment: @Jeremy C. I'm using mysql. So I guess, that I would need to create and insert the WHERE clause by myself like this:

`new SqlCommand(string.format("mysqldump --where='{0}'", clause), connection)`.

Am I correct?

Comment: I guess something like that yes, I haven't actually ever tried it myself but according to that blog it would be something in that area, except I think it's required that you include the database and table names (unless that is what you mean by clause) and you might also need to supply dbuser and dbpass

Comment: I hoped there would be a way, to do this without using strings. But maybe this will work just fine, when I use the `ToString()` method on my LINQ query, extract the where clause and pass this as argument to the SQL command.